NX automatically adds undesidered eslint plugin causing performance issues
It happened several times already that somehow NX added this:
  "plugins": [
    {
      "plugin": "@nx/eslint/plugin",
      "options": {
        "targetName": "eslint:lint",
        "extensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "html", "vue"]
      }
    }
  ]

to the nx.json config file of my project when generating a new library using npx nx g @nx/js:lib
It somehow also causes big performance issues for some of my colleagues working on the same project (but strangely not for me and other colleagues). So we have to revert this over and over again.
Does anyone know why this happens?
